Missing terminator in PowerShell CLI within a for loop using expanded variables
I want to use a for loop to replace only the 2nd match of a string in a file. To achieve this I use a PowerShell CLI command which has worked outside the for loop.
Now since I have to iterate over multiple files defined in %files% I use for /f "tokens=1" to separate file 1 from file 2 because both strings I want to replace are in file 1.
This is the for loop I am using:
for /l %%a in (1,1,2) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("!files!") do (
        set "file=%apb%\%%~b"
        echo !string[%%a]! --^> !replace[%%a]!
        rem Use PowerShell to replace only the second occurrence of a match, here `$matches[1]`.
        PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
            "$file = '!file!';" ^
            "$string = '(?m)^!string[%%a]!=.*';" ^
            "$content = Get-Content -Raw -Encoding UTF8 $file;" ^
            "$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, $string);" ^
            "if ($matches.Count -ge 2) {" ^
            "   $stringTwo = $matches[1];" ^
            "   $stringTwoPosition = $stringTwo.Index;" ^
            "   $stringTwoLength = $stringTwo.Length};" ^
            "Set-Content -NoNewLine $file -Value $content.Remove($stringTwoPosition, $stringTwoLength).Insert($stringTwoPosition, '!string[%%a]!=!string[%%a]!')"
    )
)

My issue with the for loop is, that it returns the following error:
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

All terminators are set though. I have read somewhere that expanded variables may cause issues withing PowerShell CLI commands but I have no idea how to bypass expanding the variables and getting the result I want to achieve.
I have tried calling the values of !string[%%a]! and !replace[%%a]! through non-expanded variables %stringAlias% and %replaceAlias% which did not work.
This is the rest of the snippet to prepare for the final for loop:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Set target files.
set "files=Engine\Config\BaseEngine.ini APBGame\Config\DefaultEngine.ini"
rem Initialize variables.
set "replace="
set "string="
call :subroutine.ping_optimization "%files%"
if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    set "count=1"
    for %%a in (
        "1.0"
        "5.0"
        rem ...
    ) do (
        set "replace[!count!]=%%~a"
        set /a "count+=1"
    )
)
if !errorlevel! equ 1 (
    set "count=1"
    for %%a in (
        "0.001"
        "0.001"
        rem ...
    ) do (
        set "replace[!count!]=%%~a"
        set /a "count+=1"
    )
)
set "count=1"
for %%a in (
    "AckTimeout"
    "KeepAliveTime"
    rem ...
) do (
    set "string[!count!]=%%~a"
    set /a "count+=1"
)
rem for loop causing issues goes here...


Stepping back, if you need to do a big part of the script in PowerShell anyway why not do the whole thing in PowerShell?  It has more sensible looping constructs.

Compared to the whole batch script PowerShell CLI commands are just a small part of it and I don't want convert everything to a different language especially when I'm not that familiar nor confident with PowerShell. I just use the PowerShell CLI commands to find and replace text since it seems more efficient.

The error is here : `$matches[1]`.  This is on a remark line.  You do not need the back ticks especially the second one before the period.

@jdweng Removing the backticks or \$matches[1]`` as a whole was not causing the error for me unfortunately.

@jdweng: If you had tried your recommendation, you would have realized that it makes no difference in the case at hand.
Please (a) remove your comment, which is a confusing distraction, and (b), in the future, please only
provide advice that you have verified to work as intended yourself.

If, as you say, the recommendation made no difference, is there really any harm in it remaining @mklement0? I just wanted to add that I don't even have a Windows computer, so I do not verify anything I post, unless I get feedback that it doesn't work, and I can get the use of one from somewhere.

@Compo, there is harm in it remaining: the comment is irrelevant, and anyone following its lead is likely to be confused and/or needlessly waste time. It's generally fine to post comments based on a firm grasp of the subject-matter: in that case, no explicit verification is typically needed (though the advice may situationally still be incorrect). I don't post comments like my previous one lightly, as they may be perceived as gratuitous ad hominem arguments; however, in the case at hand I perceive a pervasive pattern of unhelpful comments by a single poster, which I'm trying to discourage.

Surely, seeing an accepted answer, makes it less likely that somebody will follow a comment as if it were an answer. (Although it may be more likely to confuse since it has received an upvote). I'm not supporting jdweng, it's your battle, crack on as you please.


One of the many unfortunate behaviors of cmd.exe (the interpreter of batch files)  is that commands behave differently inside the (...)-enclosed bodies of for /f loops.
Specifically, the intra-line ^ character in "$string = '(?m)^!string[%%a]!=.*';" ^ - even though it is inside an "..." string - is inexplicably not used verbatim and requires escaping as ^^.
That is, replacing the line
"$string = '(?m)^!string[%%a]!=.*';" ^ in the code in your question with
"$string = '(?m)^^!string[%%a]!=.*';" ^ should fix your problem.
